# Object doesn't support property or method '<tabSlideOut>' error

Tags: jquery, html

I want to popup a contact form from the right side of the screen when user clicks on image. To do so, I have followed [this](http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/) link.

My code is :

```
<script src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script> // this file is in the same folder.
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'contact_tab.gif',                  //path to the image for the tab *required*
    imageHeight: '122px',                               //height of tab image *required*
    imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image *required*    
    tabLocation: 'left',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
    action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
    fixedPosition: false                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
});
});

</script>
<style>
    .slide-out-div {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #29216d;
}
</style>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slide-out-div">
            <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a>
            <h3>This is extra content</h3>
            <p>Something that wasn't important enough to be in your main body, 
           but that you wanted to hide off the side of your screen for some reason.
            </p>
            <p>Could be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

But when I run the file in browser I am getting the output :

[image]

What should I do to get the tab open perfectly to show the form?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't linked the plugin in your `html` page. Make sure you've added it after `query`

```
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
//you're missing this.
```

Comment: I added the line (as per in updated question) but getting same output.

Comment: @MohemmadK if you type in the addressbar you get nothing to display at google site. click this link to see: http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js

Comment: I downloaded the file and referenced it into my code now it is working. I downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/androidoc/downloads/detail?name=jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js&can=2&q=)

Comment: @MohemmadK Well then manually download and link the file. (that's the link they've provided in their [docs](http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html)).

Comment: Yeah thanks, and by the way thanks for entertaining my issue. @TilwinJoy

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include the jquery.tabSlideOut.js.
Look at the example code demonstrated [here](http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html) and the following line:

```
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All your scrpt and style should come under the head part of the html. please arrange it

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script> // this file is in the same folder.
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'contact_tab.gif',                  //path to the image for the tab *required*
    imageHeight: '122px',                               //height of tab image *required*
    imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image *required*    
    tabLocation: 'left',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
    action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
    fixedPosition: false                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
});
});

</script>
<style>
    .slide-out-div {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #29216d;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slide-out-div">
            <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a>
            <h3>This is extra content</h3>
            <p>Something that wasn't important enough to be in your main body, 
           but that you wanted to hide off the side of your screen for some reason.
            </p>
            <p>Could be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I added the line (as per in updated question) but getting same output.

Comment: I can see the `jquery-1.10.1.min.js` file in the debugger in IE, and it is available also. So, I am sure that it is loaded successfully

Comment: I am sure it was the error, beacuse all are right here. Please check one copy and paste the jquery path and check

Comment: put all your script and style comes in head part the html it is important it causes all error.